# snort rule explanation

Tags: snort

I'm quite new to Snort,
Could anyone explain these two rules? Specifically, why do they contain more than one "content" field ?

```
alert tcp $EXTERNAL_NET any -> $HOME_NET any (
msg:"ET TROJAN Reply Sinkhole - irc-sinkhole.cert.pl"; 
flow:established,from_server; 
content:"|3a|irc|2d|sinkhole|2e|cert|2e|pl"; 
nocase; 
fast_pattern:only; 
content:"|3a|End of MOTD command|2e|"; 
classtype:trojan-activity; 
sid:2019354; 
rev:1;)

alert tcp $HOME_NET any -> $EXTERNAL_NET $HTTP_PORTS (
msg:"ET MALWARE Adware.iBryte.B Install"; 
flow:to_server,established; 
content:"/impression.do/?"; 
http_uri; 
fast_pattern:only; 
content:"user_id="; 
http_uri; 
content:"event="; 
http_uri; 
content:"source="; 
http_uri; 
reference:md5,1497c33eede2a81627c097aad762817f; 
classtype:trojan-activity; 
sid:2018194; 
rev:4;)
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation on how snort rules work?

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand how snort processes multiple content field, and what's the goals of the rules

Comment: http://manual.snort.org/node32.html section 3.5.1

Comment: The goal is to alert when it finds these patterns - can you narrow down your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Specifically, why do they contain more than one "content" field ?

If you have multiple `content` fields, snort tries to match the first content field followed by the seconds field, etc in a recursive way. I took a **modified** example from [here](http://manual.snort.org/node36.html#SECTION00494000000000000000):

```
alert ip any any -> any any (content:"a"; content:"b";)
```

This rule would look for *a*, once that matched it then look for *b*. If successfully matched, it trigger the alert.

**fast_pattern:only**

As specified in the snort [manual](http://manual.snort.org/node382.html), it is a `content` rule modifier. Which means it applies to the previous `content` keyword. Once snort find a match for the `content` that follow with `fast_pattern`, it then starts to evaluate the rules (e.g. match other `content` keywords). To put it simply, The idea of fast_pattern is to speed up the processing without looking to match all `content` fields in the rule.

`|3a|irc|2d|sinkhole|2e|cert|2e|pl` in your first rule is used for fast pattern matching, once match is successful, snort looks for `|3a|End of MOTD command|2e|`. If fast pattern match fails, snort skips the rule.

`/impression.do/?` in your second rule is used for fast pattern matching, once match is successful, snort looks for `user_id=`, immediately followed by `event=` and immediately followed by `source=`. If fast pattern matching fails, snort skips the rule.